# Do I need to check for heteroskedasticity/heteroscedasticity only when performing regression analyses?

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, nonlinear

I don't know if this is a silly question but I haven't been able to find precise answer anywhere.

I'm building a linear regression model in R to predict a variable of interest $y$, but there are also other non linear models reported in the literature to calculate this variable. There is no need to use non linear regression to estimate any parameter of these reported models, I've got everything I need to just use the equation and calculate this $y$ variable.

I have been using functions like `ncvTest()` or `bptest()` in R to check for heteroscedasticity in the linear regression models, but I'm not quite sure if I can do the same for the literature models, which have not been part of a regression analysis of any kind.

Can I perform a test similar to the ones mentioned before to check for Heteroscedasticity in my literature models results? And if yes, what R function can I use to do it?

The reported model looks something like:

$$y=\frac{x}{\exp\biggl(0.38*\biggl(1-\sqrt\frac{t}{28}\biggl)\biggl)}$$

where x and t are known.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Sofía

Comment: The p-value calculations in linear regression rest upon these assumptions and checks, so you check these things in linear regression so that you can be sure the p-values reported are correct.  To know if you need to check these things for another model you need to know what assumptions which uses of the model rest upon.

Comment: It appears you might be using a model derived via regression for prediction. If that's the case, you should check how the model was derived and if important assumptions were checked then. For prediction you mainly need to check if the model is applicable for your data and if your data is within the "calibrated range" of the model.